# Deep Module vs SRP

Tags: oop, architecture, solid-principles

i have a message object that i can add content to. The message can also be sent. Is it better to provide a "deep module" that hides the dispatcher from the client, or is it better to have only one responsibility per class?

Example: expose the dispatcher

```
class Message {
  void add(String key, String value) { ... }
}

class Dispatcher {
  Result send(Message message) { ... }
}

class DispatcherFactory {
  Dispatcher create() { return new DefaultDispatcher(); }
}
```

Example: Hide the dispatcher

```
class MessageFactory {
   Message create() { return new Message(DefaultDispatcher()); }
}

class Message {
  Message(Dispatcher dispatcher) { ... }
 
  void add(String key, String value) { ... }
  
  Result send() {
    return dispatcher.dispatch(content);
  }
}
```

In my opinion the latter is easier to use and also testable, but violates the SRP. Which one is better?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my opinion the latter is easier to use and also testable, but violates the SRP

it does not violate SRP as implementation of `Dispatcher` class is located in `Dispatcher` class. If `Message` class would have implentation of `Dispatcher` class, then it will be violtion of SRP class.

> Which one is better?

In my view, the second implementation is better if you can slightly modify your implementation of MessageFactory [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Let me show an example:

```
class MessageFactory {
   Message create(DefaultDispatcher defaultDispatcher) 
   { return new Message(defaultDispatcher); }
}
```

### UPDATE:

If you want to have relationship publisher and subscriber. I mean publisher send messages to subscribers, then you can use `Observer` pattern.

As wiki says about [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
> named the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
> observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
> usually by calling one of their methods.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in an example of one composition relationship between two classes to suggest a Mediator.

Comment: @jaco0646 According to [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), `Mediator` dependency is injected into `Component`. And OP makes the same thing, he injects `Dispatcher` into `Message` class

Comment: Are you suggesting every application that injects a dependency is a Mediator?

Comment: @jaco0646 no, you can compare code with wiki and OP and in my view you will not find many differences

Comment: The OP is an example of one composition relationship. You can compare it with _any_ design pattern that uses composition, and not find many differences.

Comment: @jaco0646 yeah, you are right! OP uses composition. If he slightly modify his `MessageFactory` then it would comply with Mediator pattern.